# One line condition in bash

Tags: bash

I'm asked in my course HW to write a comparison in bash using just one line and without ';'.
I am required to check whether the string in the variable 'fname' ends with the letter 'C', and if so to print "Match". There is no else command. how can I do it in one line?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Do you know of the `&&`, `||` and `&` command terminators in bash?

```
[[ "${fname:(-1)}" == "C" ]] && echo Match
```

Comment: I'm a little familiar with these. I'd love to see you elaborate just a little bit here!

Comment: awesome! just what i needed :)

Answer (score -5):

I'm evil.  I like being "clever":

`echo ${fname}|sed -e 's/^.*\(.\)$/\1/' -e 's/[^C]/No  /' -e 's/.$/Match/'`

J