# How do I write conditional for loops in one line in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

For example, how could I condense

```
In [1]: for x in xrange(1,11):
...:     if x%2==0:
...:         print x
```

into one line?

Edit: Thanks guys! That was exactly what I was looking for. 
To make this a little more challenging though, is there a way to add elif & else and still have it be on one line?

To use the previous example,

```
for x in xrange(1,11):
   if x%2==0:
      print x
   else
      print "odd"
```

Comment: There isn't a "unix" programming language.  This looks like Python.

Comment: possible duplicate of [One line condition in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076561/one-line-condition-in-bash)

Comment: "on unix"? as in "in a shell script"?

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: `from subprocess import *; open('badcode.c', 'wb').write('#include <stdio.h>\nint main(){for (int x=1; x!=11; x++) if (x%2 == 0) printf("%d\n", x);}\n'); subprocess.check_call(['cc', '-o', 'badcode', 'badcode.c'; subprocess.check_call(['./badcode'])`

Comment: Obviously in real life you'd want to embed Python so you can, e.g., call `xrange(1,11)` through the C API instead of translating it to the equivalent C. But the point is, you can write code to generate, compile, and run a C program in one line. :P

Answer (score 2):

For your specific example:

```
for x in xrange(2, 11, 2): print x
```

More generally, in terms of whether you can nest blocks on one line, the answer is no. Paraphrasing the documentation on [compound statements](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html), a "suite" may not contain nested compound statements if it is in the one-line form. A "suite" is the group of statements controlled by a clause (like a conditional block or the body of a loop).

Comment: Yes, in a compound statement, the colon has to be followed by a simple statement (that is, one without a colon of its own) or an indented block.

Comment: @abarnert thanks for the confirmation. I have added a little more detail to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite the same and isn't "one line", but consider removing the side-effect and using a list filter/comprehension.

```
evens = [x for x in xrange(1,11) if x % 2 == 0]
print "\n".join(evens)
# or (now a saner "one line", the evens-expr could even be moved in-place)
for x in evens: print x
```

Comment: You've got the `join` backward. In Python, a string joins an iterable, not the other way around.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks, that was silly of me - I've corrected the code.

Comment: No, that's still wrong. `str.join` takes the `str` first, then the iterable. But you should call it with as a normal method, not an unbound method, anyway. I'll edit it if you don't mind (you can always undo my edit if you don't like it).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

map(print, [x for x in xrange(1,11) if x % 2 == 0])
```

Comment: This works, but it's ugly to use `map` for mapping side effects. Also, in Python 3.x, it won't do anything visible, because `map` just returns a (lazy) iterator, and if you never iterate it, none of those `print` calls get evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in [y for y in xrange(1,11) if y%2==0]:
  print x
```

Comment: you wrote `x` instead of `y` at the end of the list comprehension

Comment: @Gregor Thanks! It was a typo.